# Search query when clicking a tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to get the blogs that matches a tag when its clicked.
this is a code snippet:

```
const [query, setQuery] = useState("")
const [isOn, setOn] = useState('google') //by default
<Input placeholder='Search Articles' onChange={event => setQuery(event.target.value)} />
<Btnn onClick={() => setOn('google')} >Google Ads</Btnn>
<Btnn onClick={() => setOn('facebook')} >Facebook Ads</Btnn>
<Btnn onClick={() => setOn('email')}>Email</Btnn>
...
{allBlogs.filter(b =>
                {
                   
                     if (query === '') {
                      return b;
                    } else if (b.title?.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase()) ) {
                      return b;
                    }
                    else if (b.title?.toLowerCase().includes(isOn)) {
                        return b
                    }
                  }
              )
              .map((b) => 
                  (...
```

The search query works perfectly and displays all the blogs I typed in the input, however when I click on a tag like `Google` `Facebook` etc this will not display the matched blogs!
Any idea?

Comment: `event.target.value` is not what you think it is?

Comment: This is not how `filter` works btw, you should return `true` of `false`

Comment: the value of the input will be set in the hook `query` everytime I type something

Comment: It does return the array when a title matches the query's value

Comment: consoling this : ```{allBlogs.filter(b =>{if (b.title?.toLowerCase().includes(isOn) ) {console.log(b);} })}``` will show me an array their titles matches the query's value

Comment: *when I click on a tag like Google Facebook etc this will not display the matched blogs* - what is it displaying instead?

Comment: it displays nothing

Comment: Add `console.log(query)` inside `filter` and see what you get

Comment: @Konrad is correct.  Read the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) documentation and write a proper filter.